# Convert Git Repo to Darcs

Tags: git, version-control, darcs

I would like to move a git repo I have to darcs. I have not been able to find docs or projects that explain how to do this; it looks like most users want to go the other way. In addition, being able to control a git repo from darcs would be cool to.

Comment: What made you want to transition to darcs? What did git lack?

Comment: Darcs's design is far more interesting to me and for this project darcs is a better fit since it is used more by the community.

Comment: See also  the new discussion "[currently preferred way to import history from Git](http://lists.osuosl.org/pipermail/darcs-users/2015-January/027081.html)" of January 2015.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. [`git fast-export`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-import)
2. [`darcs convert import`](http://darcs.net/Using/Convert)

Comment: `darcs-fast-import` link now dead.

Comment: As is the project, apparently (mostly). The answer is 7 years old. Looks like the functionality now ships built in with Darcs. I’ve updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

darcs-fastconvert has been updated to version 0.2 : http://lists.osuosl.org/pipermail/darcs-users/2010-November/025670.html
I think this now is the safest way to do git <-> darcs bridging.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to add to gh_'s answer. [darcs-bridge](http://darcs.net/DarcsBridgeUsage) (formerly darcs-fastconvert) also uses the fast-export format.  It is built on the Darcs library (by a darcs developer) and can be installed via cabal.  It also supports marks file, which if I understand correctly, would allow for incremental conversion.

**EDIT** darcs-fastconvert has been superseded by the Darcs bridge.  I've updated the link